# Make Control Invisible on start up (no values) / Access control inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Currently i have a `LinearGradientBrush` displaying as a bar chart. The problem is on start up of my program (no values from databinding yet) i am getting white bars all across my screen, since the `GradientBrush` has no values yet and displays this as default.

How exactly do i make sure nothing shows until it actually get its databound values.

How to make this **invisible** until it get values?

Code of the `DataTemplate` and the `itemsControl` where its being used:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="icGrafiek"  
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Grafiek}}"
                ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GrafiekItemTemplate}" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="1"

<DataTemplate x:Key="GrafiekItemTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border Height="30" Margin="15" Grid.RowSpan="6">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.0,0" EndPoint="1.0,0">
                            <GradientStopCollection>                               
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="{Binding FillBar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Color="{Binding FillBar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                                <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              Color="Transparent"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                            </GradientStopCollection>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to hide the bars until there's data bound is to use Triggers to set the Visibility depending on some value.

In your DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GrafiekItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
    ...
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

You may have to use a different value than "Value" for the binding path in the DataTrigger, but this should get you started.

Comment: You probably mean Value="{x:Null}".

Comment: Hmm i cannot seem to get it bars hidden, also tried the {X:Null}. Regards Pete.

Comment: In some cases I've switched it around, using Collapsed as the default Visibility and then setting the Visibility to Visible when somevalue==something.

Comment: Hello Eirik i posted my implementation but the white bars remain for some reason. Is it not possible for example to access the GradientLinearBrush instead and set the opacity to 0 for example?

Comment: Or does this mean none of the Triggers is actually empty? The ValueBar (renamed) is actually declared in a private class as a double so i can not set it to null. Is there a alternative to work around this and still use the triggers?

Comment: Have you tried NaN as value instead of {x:Null}? You can make the double nullable by declaring it like this "double? ValueBar;". You should be able to access the GradientLinearBrush in the same way as the Grid in your DataTemplate.

Comment: Although i have no idea how it can possible be NaN at startup (since all values are declared as a double so it should be 0). But heh never thought of actually typing NaN in there figures! That works, thanks Eirik!